# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api

If someone could help me with this TypeError (Fetch). [JS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ajBk.png)

In Postman works fine:
[Postman Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCOeb.png)

Comment: Post the code and the error here. Not a picture

Comment: the error is self explanatory : you can't send a body with GET requests change it to POST or another verb

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you the problem, the fetch api doesn't allow a body to be sent with a GET request

Comment: Not really the Fetch API - it's the HTTP standard that doesn't allow it. Some tools just ignore the standard.